# Compiling static library for Unity 4.6.3 (64-bit & IL2CPP)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, static-libraries, arm64

I have a static library that I've been integrating into my Unity-iOS projects for several months now. Everything has been working fine for Unity 4.3.x.

With the recent release of Unity 4.6.3, which provides building for 64-bit devices using the IL2CPP scripting backend and Universal architecture, my static library no longer works. I have a built a very simple sample app with Unity using just the static library and it crashes at runtime.

`SDKTestApp(11555,0x199dff310) malloc: *** error for object 0x174287f2f: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Note that the project compiles just fine, but shortly after the app loads and some static library functions are executed, it crashes. And this is only problematic with those devices that are 64-bit only (iPhone 6, iPad Air, etc.).

Finally, here is the output when I run `lipo -info myStaticLibrary.a` on the (.a) file:

`myStaticLibrary.a: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
myStaticLibrary.a (for architecture arm64): current ar archive random library
myStaticLibrary.a (for architecture armv7s):    current ar archive random library
myStaticLibrary.a (for architecture armv7): current ar archive random library`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it had nothing to do with my Xcode settings, and in fact, my Xcode settings were correct. This was a bug related to my specific code.

For future reference, the lipo -info myStaticLib.a is incredibly useful to determining architecture support.